# payment-processor for multiple (bulk) memberships

Tags: civimember, webform-civicrm, payment-processor

I am trying to create a form to renew dues for multiple members at once. We do dues by member organization and not the individual.

I have a form working to do that, but need a way to bulk pay. I can't seem to figure out a API call to create a payment using a processor that doesn't create a contribution for the whole payment, since that is already being recorded at a individual level.

Does any one know if there is a CiviCRM native way to do this, or am I going to to have to write custom paypal code for this?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts:

1. The data model where Payment is recorded from a Different Contact in CiviCRM (for Membership payments) does indeed exist natively in CiviCRM. You can use this to record a Payment From the Organization.

[image]

2. The data model where if an Membership Organization has acquired a Membership -> Memberships can filter down to a specific number of Individuals who have a current/specific relationship with that Organization also exists natively in CiviCRM.

[image]

3. The data model where the Contribution is recorded at an Individual level and subsequently the Organization is also invoiced for it - that's highly unusual as it will lead to double financial records. If the Organization is paying for the Membership but the Individual is paying/perhaps this would be a reimbursement from the Organization to the Individual?
4. (preface - love Webform CiviCRM module) - if you're on Drupal - you can have a single Organization purchase memberships for any number of Individuals on one page; The monies will be recorded in that Organization's Contact Record - all Individuals will get Memberships; Add in Soft-Credits for bonus points.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up writing a custom thing to pass the info to paypal.

Comment: We basically use method 3. The individual has a membership, but to simplify things for the treasurer (and most units have their own dues on top of ours) the unit pays national. So we don't record the payment as from the unit, but apply it to individuals. So before I wrote a form in my extension for civi, the adjutant had to process each individually into the database. They now want to add credit cards as a payment option, so I was just extending that entry form to then pass the info to a payment processor.